# Marketing Cloud - Ad Studio Facebook Authorization Flow Skips FB Page Selection

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook, ad-studio

My client was going through the authorization flow for Facebook in Ad Studio. Usually, after signing in, there's a step to select the available Facebook Pages under the ad account but for one SFMC business unit, it skipped right to selecting the ad account. We were able to connect the ad account but there's concern that the Facebook Page we need won't be able to use SFMC audiences.

1. What does it mean when the authorization flow skips Page selection?
2. What is the impact?
3. Can SFMC audiences still be used on Facebook Pages that weren't selected?
4. Can one Facebook Page be connected to multiple SFMC business units? As this is a large enterprise client, there were tons of pages. We may have chosen a Page in another business unit.

Ultimately, we need to target customers for Lead Ads on these Pages. Unfortunately, I'm not able to access their FB business manager so can't prove that non-selected pages can still use audiences. It'd be great if someone has an proof that non-selected FB Pages still work!